# which of these two servers are likely to do better under heavy http load?

Tags: apache-2.2, http, centos, godaddy

As the title asks, the reason I'm asking is because I have a wordpress site which gets about 10K visitors per day on a dedicated server from iweb but in the evenings, around 8 to midnight the site crawls to a halt and page load time goes up to about 12 seconds or more compared to 2-3 during the day. Checking my google analytics its shows that traffic is pretty dispersed throughout the day so its not the case where the server is being hammered during those hours by visitors. The two server specs are:

---------------------------------- 1 -------------------------------------

OS: Linux CentOS

CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo - 2.13 GHz

RAM: 2 GB

Storage: 2 x 300 GB hard drives

Bandwidth: 1,000 GB per month

----------------------------------2 --------------------------------------

Core 2 Duo 2.4GHz (800MHz FSB)

4GB RAM

500GB SATA2

Enterprise Linux - CentOS - 64 bits

cPanel/WHM Internal

There's nothing weird in the logs for apache except Internal server error which happens a few times during those hours but not during the day and results in httpd and mysqld consuming 100% cpu for long periods of time. Load average on the server is usually about 15,15.x,15.x during those hours then in the day its 0.x,0.x,0.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that scale of visitors your constraint is more likely bandwidth & network interface & internet-connection related.  On the face of it the second machine seems better (processor, ram) but it depends on HD type/speed, and whether in the first they're in RAID.  But let's not forget backups.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I emailed my webhost and they said they'll monitor it over the next two days and try to see why it happens. I don't think its anything to do with bandwidth, the server i have is from iweb and i cant remember the numbers now but it they were pretty decent for bandwidth and connection speeds, I'll wait and see what they come out with